# Some Questions about Preimages.

Tags: general-topology, definition, examples-counterexamples

Let $f: S \rightarrow T.$ If $B \subseteq T$ and $f^{-1}(B) = \{s \in S| f(s) \in B \}.$

Give short answers to these questions, provide, where appropriate, simple examples to support your answers.

1- If $B \neq \emptyset,$ can it be that $f^{-1}(B) = \emptyset $?

2- Can it happen that $f^{-1}(B) = S $?

3- Is it true that $f(f^{-1}(B)) = B $?

4- Is it true that $f^{-1}(f(A)) = A?$

** My trials:**

1-No, for example if $B = \{ 1\}$ then we are sure by the definition of $f^{-1}(B)$ we are sure that there exists $s \in S$ such that $f(s) = 1 \in B$, hence $f^{-1}(B) \neq \emptyset .$

2- yes, but I am unable to build an example, my difficulty is in choosing the function definition, could anyone help me in this?

3- & 4- I do not know how to think about them, I am caring about teaching me to think about the question not about the final answer, could anyone help me in these 2 questions please?

Comment: For 3 can f be a many one function?

Comment: what do you mean by a many one function? @ArchisWelankar

Comment: ref 1- What if $B = \{1\}$ and $f$ maps everything in $S$ to $2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer to 1. is incorrect. Just consider a function which is not surjective, and let $B$ be a set of elements that is disjoint from the range of $f$.

Regarding 2, the answer is yes, just take $B=T$.

3 and 4 are false in general. To get a counterexample of 3, just choose any $B$ that contains an element not belonging to the image of $f$. For 4, you can get a counterexample by considering the function $f\colon \{1,2\}\to \{1\}$ and $A=\{1\}$.

Comment: What about the rest of my questions?

Comment: How can I think about 3- & 4- upon seeing them for the first time?

Comment: You can draw a picture of the function visually by drawing arrows from a sequence of $|S|$ dots to a sequence of $|T|$ dots. By definition of a function, there must be exactly one arrow starting at each of the $|S|$ dots, but there can be $0,1,$ or many arrows entering any given one of the $|T|$ dots. Then you can visually see what these different sets represent. Other than that, just start from the definitions...

Comment: Can 2 happen if $f$ is 1-1 ?

Comment: Can 2 happen if $f$ is onto ? if $B = R_{f}$? I think it can ... am I correct?